# Can not decipher all the lines with rsa

Tags: python-2.7, encryption, text, rsa, sage

I can not cipher and decipher all the lines in my text file, code below only ciphers and deciphers the very last line

```
p = random_prime(2 ** 128, 2 ** 256)
q = random_prime(2 ** 128, 2 ** 256)
rsa=RSA(p,q)
lines=[line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('plaintext.txt', 'rb') ]
txt=open('encrypted.txt', 'wb')
content='\n'.join(lines)
print content
length=len(content)
content=rsa.encrypt(content)
plaintext =rsa.decrypt(content,length)
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: You cannot use RSA to encrypt arbitrary files. You're limited to plaintexts which are smaller than the modulus.

Comment: so should I readlines to an array then apply rsa or do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: It's usually done in conjunction with a symmetric cipher like AES: [Hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)

Comment: oh I see, But I need to use rsa this is for homework,  I will post another question instead of editing this, could you take a look at that too please ? [http://stackoverflow.com/q/33334455/5486575]